# Cannot find choose the Embedded JDK option in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#jdk), the `choose the Embedded JDK` option should be found under `File > Settings... > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle`. But I do not see it there. Just updated Android Studio to the latest version `Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 1`.

Previously I was testing with the Oracle JDK, but discovered that the OpenJDK is embedded and would like to use that instead.

How can the embedded JDK be selected?

[image]

Comment: Facing the same issue, none of the answers seems to work. I am going to try reinstalling Android Studio if I can't find the solution... I've been looking for a while already!

Comment: Even reinstalling android studio didn't fix the issue...

Comment: I still couldn't find a way of accessing the Embedded JDK option in the Gradle section, but I came here due to this issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/265713286, and I fixed it with this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69448462/the-supplied-javahome-seems-to-be-invalid-i-cannot-find-the-java-executable-tr/75108953#75108953

Answer (score 1):

Go to the **project structure** and then select the `Gradle` setting then you can find the `JDK` location that is embedded with **Android Studio**. [image: Embeded JDK location update on Android studio]

Comment: I can't find this "Gradle" setting. My project Structure window looks different: https://i.imgur.com/CJVCsaT.png

Answer (score -1):

You need to have a project open before you follow those directions in the documentation. The Gradle JDK is configured on a per-project basis.

[image]

Comment: Even with a project open, these options are not available.

Comment: @crayden it has to be a Gradle project. So when you open the project, you need to be opening the directory that directly contains the `build.gradle` file.