# i get this error after update Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, visual-studio-code, gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found 3 links where people faced the same or something similar to what you are having. I hope these help! :)

[IntelliJ Gradle Plugin: The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29356796/intellij-gradle-plugin-the-supplied-javahome-seems-to-be-invalid)

[Android Studio - supplied javaHome is not a valid folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22749200/android-studio-supplied-javahome-is-not-a-valid-folder)

[The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69448462/the-supplied-javahome-seems-to-be-invalid-i-cannot-find-the-java-executable-tr)

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

If someone faces this error after Android Studio update to Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 than simply follow following steps:

1. Go To Android Studio directory (default `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio`) and remove jre folder.
2. Run cmd as administrator.
3. Write: `cd C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio`
4. Write `mklink /D "jre" "jbr"`

Answer (score 0):

If someone facing a problem with update from AS Electric Eel 2022.1.1 **patch 1** to AS Electric Eel 2022.1.1 **patch 2**, the following solution worked for me: 
1\ Create an empty file `/jre/bin/.marker` in AS folder 
2\ Run update again

Note: 
since AS Electric Eel 2022.1.1 patch 1 there is no `jre` folder, but `jbr` folder exists instead

My environment:
Windows 11 
AS folder is c:/android/android_studio