# I needed to install Java 11 and now vs code keeps trying to use 21 as this was the old JDK, how do I change it

Tags: java, flutter, visual-studio-code

Upon trying to run any flutter app in vs code I am getting this error as I had to change the JDK to 11 to get my SHA keys. How do I change it?

Here is the error message:

> The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin\java.exe

Comment: If the answers in the duplicate are confusing you (because the top-voted once all talk about Android Studio), you specifically need to look at [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69457847/466862) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77013606/466862). In other words, your JAVA_HOME is probably still pointing to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21` and needs to be modified to point to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11` (or whatever the installation directory is).