# React Native Windows: "The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable"

Tags: java, windows, react-native

I am having some trouble runnning React Native after uninstalling JDK 21 in order to do a downgrade to version 17 due to `react-native doctor` suggestions.

The error messages says:

> The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin\java.exe

I searched for `javaHome` variable in my enviroment or system but it does not exist. Since it not resembles to the common windows variable nomenclature like `JAVA_HOME` I tried to set this variable in my system but didn't work.

These are my system variables right now:

[image]

Where can I find this variable and change its value to link it into the JDK 17 directory?

**ABOUT DUPLICATE FLAG:** The post I mentioned and marked as duplicated by **ARE NOT THE SAME ISSUE**, the post mentioned only solved a side problem involved in the searching of a solution of the main problem. While `JAMA_HOME` and `javaHome` variables may sound equal, they are not the same (this is implied too by React Native by giving different errors for both variables and thier path). Even after setting the correct path of `JAVA_HOME`, the problem with `javaHome` persists

**UPDATE:** I removed `\bin` to `JAVA_HOME` variable path since it showed a different error after terminal restart, but the original error persists

Comment: What is the different error? And is `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` on your Path?

Comment: Hi, I lost the error already, but same error and solution was found in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45182717/java-home-is-set-to-an-invalid-directory

Comment: Anyway, I have just solved the main post problem in this moment. I will write what I did

Comment: Your JAVA_HOME should point to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17`, **not** `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin`.

Comment: Did that, it is specified in **update** section, but that wasn't the problem, as stated in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking for solution by hours I ended up in this post [The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69448462/the-supplied-javahome-seems-to-be-invalid-i-cannot-find-the-java-executable-tr), where, in the answer of @Fedor, a user named @ubershmekel made a comment saying he had to **delete an old empty SDK** folder in order to `Flutter` for looking into the new SDK (downgraded) version. I did the same thing and it just worked.

I think the `javaHome` variable may be related to some `Android Studio` configuration, but I was never able to find where the value or the variable itself are stored